# Copy WooCommerce Product Short Description to Product Long Descrition in database

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have a client site that has about 800 WooComm products.

All the single product description text content has been captured in the "Product Short Description" area and not in the "Product Long Description" area of a single product page.

I need to bulk copy the content from "Product Short Description" to "Product Long Description".

...and possibly bulk delete the "Product Short Description" afterwards.

Maybe I can do this in the database via PHPMyAdmin?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this simple SQL query that will copy Product Short Description to Product Long Description:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET `post_content` = `post_excerpt`
WHERE `post_type` = 'product'
AND `post_status` = 'publish'
```

**Always make a database backup before (in particular `wp_posts` table).**

Tested and works

---

Once done you it's better and more secure to empty the short description afterwards with:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET `post_excerpt` = ''
WHERE `post_type` = 'product'
AND `post_status` = 'publish'
```

Tested and works

---

> If it doesn't work for you, check that your tables prefix should all start with `wp_` … If not, replace `wp_` by your specific prefix.

Comment: Thanks for that but it yields the following error: #1054 - Unknown column 'post_content' in 'field list'

Comment: As OP wants to 'move' the data from short description to description code can be modified to ```SET `post_content` = `post_excerpt`, `post_excerpt` = ''```. This will first move the data and then empty the short description field.

Comment: @DhavalShah Thanks I didn't read it all… But please avoid editing my answers (or other people answers)… Use comments instead. it's softer as StackOverFlow philosophy…

Comment: Thanks Loic, this should have worked but it didn't. I had no errors this time but however nothing was copied. Any ideas?

Comment: @FanusvanStraten I have just tested now, and it works just perfect… May be you have check that the prefix is `wp_` if not you need to change it to your specific prefix.

Comment: @FanusvanStraten Reason should be `$table_prefix` is set to something else than `wp_` in `wp_config.php` . Check `wp_config.php` and update above code with `UPDATE {table_prefix}_posts`.

Comment: Great, youre a cape wearing superstar Loic ;-) All sorted and thanks for the tip on removing the short description afterwards since that was my next question.